# Android Layout Preview not matching with the Deployed App in Device?

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

[image: Layout Preview in AndroidStudio]

I used the Andorid Support Library to make a Card layout and implemented TextView and Image view in it.

Card View XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/originLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOrigin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="BOM"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDeparture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="20:45"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/originLayout"
                android:src="@drawable/flight" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/destiLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDesti"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="GOA"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvArrival"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="21:45"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I deploy this in my App, the Relative Layout gets cluttered and all the TextViews and ImageView gets on top of each other.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `toEndOf` is  api17+. check that your device has the right android version.

Comment: Also, your elements are one after the other. A LinearLayout would be simpler and equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 android:layout_toEndOf
```

better use

```
android:layout_below
```

toEndOf and toStartOf is added recently in API level 17 i.e. android 4.2 versions so it will not be found in lower versions of android

Comment: a/ no. b/ you say that, but why?

Answer (score 0):

XML Layout is not bad designed. I messed up with layout_toEndOf as it is not supported by devices below API 17. However, my test device was of API 14. I added the tag layout_toRightOf to the XML and now, it renders perfectly in the Test Device.